# Grails: Is it possible to avoid lazy services initialization?

Tags: spring, grails

I've got a service that registers JSON marshallers. I've added `@PostConstruct` method that registers marshallers.

But my service it's not initialized because nobody uses it. I need to inject it to initialize it. Can I mark it to initialize on Grails startup? I can inject it into BootStrap.groovy but it's obvious why BootStrap.groovy do need it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a `lazyInit` property

```
class MyService {    
  boolean lazyInit = false

  @PostConstruct
  void init() {
    // this will now be executed at startup because the service is eagerly created
  }
}
```

This property defaults to `true` if omitted, so service beans are lazy by default.